# Array in javascript not working in the right way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a strange problem and it should be solved in less than 1 minute. I really can't understand why is not working.

I have a bidimensional array "gridShip" and I'm doing stuff with this array.

This is the code:

```
gridShip[i][j].stat = "ship";
gridShip[i][j+1].stat = "ship";
gridShip[i][j-1].stat = "ship";
```

After that I print in console the 3 cell of the array.

The first are working, the third one no! I have no errors and I check if I don't get out of the array size.

Make no sense for me.

Comment: You need to show us the full context of the code.

Comment: give more code for us to understand

Comment: what do you mean it's not working, what is not doing? and btw you shouldn't use arrays for key value pairs. i.e. no .stat = "ship" on your arrays

Comment: The code you have provided is going to error with `ReferenceError: gridShip is not defined`. You need to provide a *complete* reduced test case.

Answer (score 1):

That works for me

```
var i=0; j=1;
var gridShip = [];
gridShip[i] = [{},{},{}];
gridShip[i][j].stat = "ship";
gridShip[i][j+1].stat = "ship";
gridShip[i][j-1].stat = "ship";
```

tell us more details.